# rowcount and db size not same after migration from mysql 5 to mysql 8

Tags: mysql, migration, upgrade, mysql5

I upgraded my database from mysql 5 to mysql 8.
After backup from mysql 5 and restore to mysql 8, the db size and the rowcount for table isn't same.
Is there any explanation why because the log show nothing?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i try to know why there is differences  between db size and rowcount after the migration.